# express js 4 - How to configure without app.configure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Express js 4.0 is released now and my express 3-app is not working after updating because `app.configure()` was removed in the new version.

My Express 3-config looks like this:

```
// all environments
app.configure(function()
{
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    // ...
});

// NODE_ENV=development only
app.configure('development', function()
{
    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
    // ...
});

// NODE_ENV=production only
app.configure('production', function()
{
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
    // ...
});
```

My Question: What is the best practice for configuring an express 4 app depending on the NODE_ENV environment variable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest if you are making this conversion, you read through the [`3.x` to `4.x` conversion guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x).

Specifically:

```
app.configure('development', function() {
   // configure stuff here
});
// becomes
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if ('development' == env) {
   // configure stuff here
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the link! now i know where to look for information about newer versions of express :-)